# Windows 10: How to turn off this particular snap windows feature

Tags: windows-10

Recently upgraded to Windows 10 and whenever I move a window, this 2x4 tile comes up in the top-middle of the screen. Dragging currently selecting window to one of this boxes snaps the window to the corresponding screen-size. How do I get rid of this grid?

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: This actually seems useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it. It was due to 'MSI True Color' program, which is a bundled program. Disabling this turns off the 2x4 snap tiles.

Answer (score 4):

I bought a new laptop a few weeks back and this has been bothering me to no end as well. It's always in the way, and you can easily use windows key + arrow keys to partition windows.

Anyways, if you open MSI true colour, click show settings, then tools, then desktop partition. Then uncheck desktop partition on and it'll stop showing the boxes.

Answer (score 3):

Open the "MSI True Color" program, select "Show Settings" -> "Tools" -> "Desktop Partition," then uncheck "Desktop Partition on" (it may simply look red when checked, gray when unchecked).

Comment: Mate, the question is more than 2 years old and already has an accepted answer. Not sure what you're adding that hasn't already been covered by other answers.

Comment: Clear, detailed steps. That's what I added.

Comment: @Meta747 because the accepted answer is not the best answer and the other similar answer is harder to read

Answer (score 0):

The feature that supplies the overlay is called "Snap Assist" and is a subfeature of Windows Aero Snap.  Because it is a subfeature, both must be "on" for Snap Assist to be active, but you can deactivate Snap Assist without deactivating all of Aero Snap.

(Geez, all this "snap this and that" gets confusing.  I can hardly follow my own explanation!)

There is a very good write-up of various ways to turn these features on and off, at https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4343-turn-off-aero-snap-windows-10-a.html

Too long; didn't read?

Open CMD.EXE and type the following at the prompt:

```
REG ADD HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced /v SnapAssist /t REG_DWORD /d 0
```

If it doesn't work, you may have to run CMD.EXE elevated (i.e. Run As Administrator), and you may also need to add the "/f" flag to the above command.

Hope this helps!